# How to edit css in an angular app with external libraries

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I am having a problem editing css for divs that are next to or enclosing components from external libraries. Its like any css I write is overridden by these external packages.

I am using [core-ui](https://coreui.io/angular/docs/getting-started/introduction) and [Taiga UI](https://taiga-ui.dev/getting-started#install) in my angular application.

**Example 1:**

I can't change the z-index of the [carousel](https://coreui.io/angular/docs/components/carousel/). All other divs are ALWAYS beneath the carousel, no matter where I place them or change the z-index.

For example I want the second div below to be ontop of the first:

```
<div class="min-h-[56em] z-0">
  <c-carousel [dark]="true">
    <c-carousel-indicators></c-carousel-indicators>
    <c-carousel-inner>
      <c-carousel-item *ngFor="let slide of slides">
        <img
          [src]="slide.src"
          alt="{{ slide.title }}"
          class="d-block w-100"
          loading="lazy"
        />
      </c-carousel-item>
    </c-carousel-inner>
    <c-carousel-control
      [routerLink]
      caption="Previous"
      direction="prev"
    ></c-carousel-control>
    <c-carousel-control
      [routerLink]
      caption="Next"
      direction="next"
    ></c-carousel-control>
  </c-carousel>
</div>

<div class="flex justify-center -mt-72 z-[1100]">
   Some other content I want to be on top of the above carousel
</div>
```

I tried editing scss as shown [here](https://coreui.io/docs/layout/z-index/) but that didn't help as the carousel is not included in that list.

```
$zindex-dropdown:                   1000;
$zindex-sticky:                     1020;
...
```

**Example 2**

Here the [paginator](https://primeng.org/paginator) is not being positioned as intended

```
<div class="mx-10 mt-5 flex justify-center">
  <div class="w-11/12 lg:w-5/6">
    <tui-pagination
      [activePadding]="activePadding"
      [length]="64"
      [index]="0"
    ></tui-pagination>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried giving my css priority as described [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important), still nothing. Its like angular gives the components priority when rendering or something.

How do I go about this? How do I give my css priority?